# What is the earliest version of TinyXML that correctly translates character entities?

Tags: xml, character, entities, tinyxml, character-entities

According to [TinyXML documentation](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/index.html), the latest version of the software correctly translates the standard five XML character entities (&, ", ', >, <) into their human-readable equivalent when you call Value() on a TiXmlText object.

By contrast, this documentation also states that, "Older versions of TinyXML 'preserved' character entities, but the newer versions will translate them into characters."

I am currently using TinyXML 2.5.3, and calling Value() on a TiXmlText object preserves the character entities in the return value.

Was character entity translation only implemented as a TinyXML feature starting in version 2.6?  Or should my character entities be translating properly in 2.5.3 and something else is going wrong?

Many thanks for your help!